# How to set-up Corda on Cloud Foundry environment?

Tags: cloud-foundry, corda

I am trying to set-up corda on cloud foundry environment.
Is it possible?
https://docs.corda.net/head/getting-set-up.html

I know how to change OpenJDK to OracleJDK.
What I don't know is to install Git and IntelliJ IDEA on the same application.
In the first place, is it silly to set-up corda on cloud Foundry?

Regards,
Yohei

Comment: Do you want to run a node using Cloud Foundry, or develop CorDapps on Cloud Foundry?

Comment: Thank you for question.
I want to run nodes using Cloud Foundry.

Answer (score 1):

Running a Corda node is effectively just running a JAR file. The only requirement once you've created the node folder is the Oracle JDK.

You can find instructions for deploying nodes on Linux machines here: https://docs.corda.net/deploying-a-node.html. These instructions should apply to Cloud Foundry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'm not familiar with Cloud Foundry, so I'm not sure if Corda node works with Cloud Foundry.
I'm going to try to build it.